# Fuse distributed tx manager doesn't release DB sessions

Tags: oracle, distributed-transactions, fuseesb, geronimo, aries

We have an OracleXADataSource that is being wrapped by Apache Aries in Fuse Fabric (like in  [this article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/EIP_Transaction_Guide/files/XaJdbc-DataSources.html)). If I keep sending a lot of request to the server, it starts throwing the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

When I check the sessions using the following query, after every request in Oracle, it keeps showing an increased number under *current utilization*.

```
select resource_name, current_utilization, max_utilization, limit_value 
from v$resource_limit 
where resource_name in ('sessions', 'processes', 'transactions');
```

`CURRENT_UTILIZATION   MAX_UTILIZATION       LIMIT_VALUE
processes    545                   768             800
sessions     553                   774            1222
transactions   0                     0      UNLIMITED`

Most of the recommendations for this issue says to increase the *processes* and *session* limits in Oracle, but this would solve the problem temporarily, until we reach a certain load I'm affraid.

I found/tried the followings so far:

- Perodically when the load increases (or certain amount of time spent) the *session* and *processes* get decreased with a bigger amount (100-200). (I guess Geronimo periodically releases the sessions). At the same time when a number of sessions are released, the active transactions column shows the same amount:

`CURRENT_UTILIZATION   MAX_UTILIZATION       LIMIT_VALUE
processes    355                   768             800
sessions     363                   774            1222
transactions 122                   122       UNLIMITED`

- If I shut down Fuse, the *processes* values goes back to initial size immediately (so the issue is on client side)
- If I turn off the distributed transaction support, then everything is fine and *processes* doesn't increase at all
- I tried adding pooling to the OracleXADataSource, but nothing has changed (it's deprecated, but I assume it still works. We don't have the [UCP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm#CHDGEJJF) jar unfortunately, so I couldn't test it with that)

  ```
  <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
  <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
      <props merge="default">
          <prop key="InitialLimit">1</prop>
          <prop key="MinLimit">1</prop>
          <prop key="MaxLimit">1</prop>
      </props>
  </property>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resolve this issue using Aries unfortunately. I consider it a bug. However I managed to make it properly work using Atomikos, which I strongly recommend. Much more straightforward than using Aries' built in auto-proxy behavior: you declare everything so you know what actually happens.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="userTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp"> 
   <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"> 
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> 
   <property name="userTransaction" ref="userTransaction" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="oracledb" />
    <property name="xaDataSource">
        <bean class="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource">
            <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:${db.port}:${db.sid}"/>
            <property name="user" value="${db.schema}" />
            <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```